# Android - Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have recently upgraded to Flutter 3.0. And later I encountered an issue after trying to run. After it finished downloading Gradle 6.7 and on starting Gradle Daemon, I got this error

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.pom'.
> > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/34.95.74.180] failed: connect timed out

And as the way Flutter handles the error, I stuck in loop with it redownloading the gradle zip file on and on for reason I don't know and resulting the same error endlessly.

Comment: I don't use flutter, but from logs I suggest that you need to remove jcenter from repositories and add mavenCentral() instead of it.

Answer (score 2):

After followed @curioushikhov's answer by commented out `jcenter()` and replace it with `mavenCentral()` in `android/build.gradle`'s `repositories` bracket, the error is gone.

Turns out the error is caused by connection timeout. I blame the server since my connection was fine. More similar errors occur after. I have to repeatedly run `gradlew clean` to completely get pass through it all.

(For Flutter user). Similar errors also occurred on Flutter's app build. The problem with Flutter is once it occurs, it simply removes, redownloads and run gradle from begin repeatedly, cause it to redownload everything to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: seems like they have already shut down the jcenter()

Comment: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10. , absolutely it worked. :D and currently my repositories  are: 
`mavenLocal()
  google()
  mavenCentral()`